# How can I make my custom taxonomy term dynamic?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

How can I make my custom taxonomy term dynamic? I have custom post type 'review' and custom taxonomy 'writer' connected to it.

This works O.K.

```
<?php
// Loop arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'review',
    'writer'=>  'alice-munro',
    'showposts' => 6
);
```

Is it possible to replace 'alice-munro' with code which will chose the correct writer and show posts related to his/her name?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `author_name` or `author`?

Comment: In which page you want to display this code.. if the writers are the registered subscibers then it should be in author.php or if they are your own created categories (taxonomy terms) then it should go in archive page or taxonomy-<taxonomy_name>.php

Comment: Sorry, but the way your question is written it's like you just have to create a variable like `$author`, set it's value with `$author = $_GET['author']` or something like that and use `'writer' => $author`. Is that what you want? If it isn't I would advise you to rephrase the question :)

Comment: O.K. I'll rephrase the question.

Comment: 'writer' is my own custom taxonomy term, and I listed all writers in the sidebar. If I click on one of them I get all his/her books in the taxonomy.php. But I have also single post for every writer (short biography) and I would like to show there also all his/her books as thumbnails (jus like in the tahonomy.php). Code works perfectly if I set writers name ('writer'=>  'alice-munro',) but if I use ('writer' => $author) (Felipe Elia sugestion) I get books from all writers ... and that is not what I want.